# Change the audio track on a video

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to switch the audio language of a video.

With `video.audioTracks` I can see the list of the available tracks which looks like this

[image]

How can I access a track to enable/disable it? 
I tried `video.audioTracks[0]` but it returns an undefined.

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle ?

Comment: If audioTracks is an object, it is possible the `0` and `1` are strings, did you try with `video.audioTracks['0']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a method to access an audio track from the AudioTrackList :

```
audioTracks.getTrackById(id) // get AudioTrack object by id
```

Source : [HTML Audio/Video DOM audioTracks Property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_audiotracks.asp)